# Custom discovery with Web Platform Installer

Tags: web-platform-installer

I want to use the Web Platform Installer to perform installations and manage dependencies, but because we store version information in a database, the options for discovery that are supported by the WPI won't work for us.

Based on what I've learned so far setting up a custom feed, I don't even know how you would inject any sort of custom logic into the application, but I thought I'd better throw a question out here before I give up.

Is it possible to add custom logic for how the Web Platform Installer discovers which services have been installed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I've been able to tell, this is not possible.  We ended up coming up with a custom solution to fit our needs.

For those interested, chocolatey (http://nuget.org/List/Packages/chocolatey) is another great utility for custom installations.